# Jacoco Kotlin Dsl Multimodule exclude

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to exclude some files from the merged jacoco report. I am using:

(root gradle)

```
    tasks.register<JacocoReport>("codeCoverageReport") {
    subprojects {
        val subProject = this
        subProject.plugins.withType<JacocoPlugin>().configureEach {
            subProject.tasks.matching { it.extensions.findByType<JacocoTaskExtension>() != null }.configureEach {
                val testTask = this
                sourceSets(subProject.sourceSets.main.get())
                executionData(testTask)
            }

            subProject.tasks.matching { it.extensions.findByType<JacocoTaskExtension>() != null }.forEach {
                rootProject.tasks["codeCoverageReport"].dependsOn(it)
            }
        }
    }

    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = false
        html.isEnabled = true
        csv.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

And for the every module exclusion jacoco report (e.g. for common module):

```
tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
            exclude(JacocoExcludes.commonModule)
        }
    )
}
```

For each module this is working but when trying to interact with root gradle task either the gradle sync fails or it only add the files from the last module. Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used the following code :

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    // tests are required to run before generating the report
    dependsOn(tasks.test) 
    // print the report url for easier access
    doLast {
        println("file://${project.rootDir}/build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html")
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it) {
                exclude("**/generated/**", "**/other-excluded/**")
            }
        })
    )
}
```

as suggested here : https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1176#issuecomment-610643709